# Powershell Array replace value

Tags: arrays, csv, powershell, multidimensional-array

This is probably a very simple question but I am new to powershell arrays.

I have a multidimensional array in powershell which is populated from a CSV file. eg:

```
$data = Import-CSV \\filelocation\file.csv
$data

company       emailaddress
-------       ------------
company1      emailaddress1
company2      emailaddress2
```

I can view a specific value in the array with the following:

```
write-host $data.emailaddress{1]
```

which will output: "company2".

I want to be able to replace a string in the array but if I use the following:

```
$data.emailaddress[1] = "NEWemailaddress"
```

and

```
write-host $data.emailaddress{1]
```

then the data is still the same.

How do I get the value to overwrite?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you have is an array of objects not a multi dimensional array. Try this:

```
$data[1].emailaddress = "NEWemailaddress"
```